# How to fix/adjust git log result's indentation in terminal

Tags: git, terminal, indentation, git-log

In VS Code terminal on Windows,

I am trying to display my commits by using `git log` and somehow, the displayed result's indentation are broken.

AFAIK, I accidentally pressed arrow keys which move the screen of terminal in VS Code to the right.

I git add and commit them like this:

```
    feature/POR-1-landing-page-ui
      * Remove @webpack-cli/generators
      * Sanitize spaces to tabs
```

But the indents appear like this when I `git log`

and there's large indent between the `*` and `#commit messages`.

```
$ git log

commit b153284 (HEAD -> feature/POR-1-landing-page-ui)

    feature/POR-1-landing-page-ui
            *       Remove @webpack-cli/generators
            *       Sanitize spaces to tabs
```

---

This is how I want the indents to be displayed. When there are too many changes, it's difficult to read the commit messages because of the large indents.

```
commit 7a0dcb4

    feature/POR-1-landing-page-ui
      * Sanitize imports
      * Sanitize indents
      * Sanitize folder name
```

I tried to restart the integrated terminal first and still the same, afterwards tried restarting vscode nothing happens also. I checked VS Code settings but nothing was modified.

Comment: `git log` adds four spaces in front of the commit log message data by default. Other than that it just sends it directly *to* the terminal or through a pager to the terminal; interpretation of spaces, tabs, escape sequences, and the like are up to the pager (if you're using one) and then the terminal. Using `--format` or `--pretty=format`, you can control the data that Git sends out, but the rest remains up to the pager and/or terminal. (Bash, whether adapted for Windows or not, is not really relevant here.)

Comment: You should always have a blank line between the first and following lines in the commit message (it is really bad that vscode does not have syntax highlighting to indicate that lack of a blank line is an error). Also the following lines are normally not indented (you might do that for command examples/output for instance, but not for just normal text/descriptions).

Comment: @hlovdal, I didn't know that you should put a blank line between the title and commit messages or else it will cause error. Thanks! What tools are you using that it will show an error if no blank line between title and body?

Comment: [Vim highlights with read](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37282830/23118) when the blank line separating the first line which is the subject line (and is the one shown for `--oneline` for instance) and the body is missing . [Here](https://cbea.ms/git-commit/) is a good read about more commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

Just figure out a workaround for this

Using VS Code commit editor just replace the indents to spaces

`Convert indents to spaces` from the settings before committing.

Because the terminal is interpretting indents as 4 spaces mentioned by @torek

> git log adds four spaces in front of the commit log message data by default. Other than that it just sends it directly to the terminal or through a pager to the terminal; interpretation of spaces, tabs, escape sequences, and the like are up to the pager (if you're using one) and then the terminal.

```
commit 7a0dcb4

    feature/POR-1-landing-page-ui
      * Sanitize imports
      * Sanitize indents
      * Sanitize folder name
```